# What is the gradient operator in this context?

Tags: vector-analysis, computer-science, convolution, image-processing, compression

I've been trying to learn math recently by implementing papers that I find related to projects I'm working on. Usually when I encounter a problem, I just google it, find the answer and continue on but this excerpt from a paper I'm reading is getting me really stuck. This is taken from a paper on edge detection in images compressed using the discrete cosine transform. I'm pretty sure I have a solid understanding of what the convolution operator is but the part about a row and column gradient operators is confusing me.

[Paper Excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsirv.png)

After googling around for it, I understand that it is supposed to essentially estimate the derivative, however I still don't understand what the specific row and column versions are supposed to be doing. Any help explaining what the row and column gradient operators are would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The derivative here is a gradient, which is a magnitude and a direction, hence a vector.  The vector can be decomposed into horizontal and vertical components.  The row gradient operator gives the horizontal component (essentially by ignoring vertical variation) and the column gradient operator gives the vertical component (essentially by ignoring the horizontal variation).  Is there more to your question?

Comment: @EricTowers that is very helpful, thank you.